# JS Typescript Object filtering

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const propsSelector = (props:any) => {

    let newProps: object = {}

    Object.keys(props).forEach((prop) => {
      if (typeof props[prop] !== 'undefined') {
        Object.assign(newProps, {
          [prop]: props[prop]
        })
      } 
    })
    return newProps
  }

const selectedProps:any = propsSelector(props)
```

**Is there a more efficient way to filter objects?** I would love a reduce like method for objects.

**Every idea or observation is welcomed!**

Comment: (I don't believe `props:any`. `propertied`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` instead, to get an array of entries (an entry is an array of the key and the value), filter it by whether the value is undefined, then use `Object.fromEntries` to turn it back into an object:

```
const propsSelector = (props: object) => {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(props)
            .filter(([_, val]) => val !== undefined)
    );
};
```

```js
const propsSelector = (props) => {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(props)
            .filter(([_, val]) => val !== undefined)
    );
};

console.log(propsSelector({
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: undefined
}));
```

Also:

- Best to type functions precisely, and [avoid using `any`](https://itnext.io/avoiding-any-in-typescript-advanced-types-and-their-usage-691b02ac345a), since that loses type safety - if you use `any` everywhere, you may as well not be using Typescript at all, to some extent. If you don't know anything about what an argument will be, type it as `unknown` and use type guards to check it inside the function.
- [Don't use `let`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6), always use `const` when possible
- When assigning a plain property to an object, no need for `Object.assign` - simple `=` assignment works just fine. (`newProps[prop] = props[prop];`)

> I would love a reduce like method for objects.

You *can* use `reduce` here, but it's [arguably not very appropriate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) since the accumulator is the same object each time.

```js
const propsSelector = (props) => {
    return Object.entries(props).reduce((a, [prop, val]) => {
      if (val !== undefined) {
        a[prop] = val;
      }
      return a;
    }, {});
};

console.log(propsSelector({
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: undefined
}));
```

Comment: Wooow! That's a thorough answer! I would upvote you but I don't have the permission yet :)
Thank you!